How to meta-analyze when one condition has more replicates (within study) than another?
I am wondering how I can test, overall, does model X or model Y have greater prediction skill (pearson correlation coefficient)? It seems a meta-analytical approach is best suited, but is it possible to analyze all data points or must I average within model X? I have 82 individual studies with each study containing at least 2 data points for model X (up to 50 data points), and only 1 data point for model Y. Each data point is a pearson correlation coefficient. Thank you for your help!
Here is a snippet of my dataframe:



Study
model_X
model_Y




1
0.997215692
0.8173659


1
0.98983977
NA


2
0.268916285
0.4627209


2
0.465654927
NA


2
0.3258427
NA


3
0.997865356
0.9757006


3
0.997643917
NA


3
0.999635711
NA


4
0.993754226
0.9749648


4
0.99775874
NA


4
0.998962641
NA


5
0.91913898
0.9568082


5
0.953742709
NA


6
0.857751119
0.8895688


6
0.928701853
NA


6
0.973800937
NA


6
0.961525817
NA


6
0.863833918
NA


6
0.907017542
NA


6
0.82059694
NA


6
0.955266593
NA


6
0.866640624
NA


6
0.928966429
NA


6
0.969869205
NA


6
0.920471317
NA


6
0.955048379
NA


6
0.974908989
NA


6
0.98525563
NA


6
0.936951014
NA




Bump. Any help would be much appreciated!

It seems that taking the average value of model_x per study is possibly the only way to do it.
